# How does the Duplicate() function help protect data integrity?

Tags: coldfusion

1. I would like to understand the
   purpose of the Duplicate() function
   when used on a variable before it's
   returned by a function. It would be nice if you
   could provide an example of when the
   use of Duplicate() is important or
   necessary.
2. Does it have other purposes?

I have heard others mention Duplicate() in the context of data integrity, and I would like to get a better understanding of how it works and when to use it.

I often see this:

```
<cfreturn Duplicate(local.myVariable)>
```

When this also returns the same result:

```
<cfreturn local.myVariable>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While most variables are [passed by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) in ColdFusion, Structures are not -- they are [passed by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), which can cause unintentional overwriting of values, if you aren't careful.

Using `Duplicate()` creates an identical copy of the variable in another location in memory, so that when it is passed by reference (note that you are still passing by reference, there is no way to force a pass by value) any changes made to the data from the caller do not affect the source of the return.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate is used for passing variables by value than reference .

Structures in ColdFusion are usually passed by refrence if you use

cfset struct1 = struct2

To avoid changes in struct1 while updating struct2, we use

cfset struct1 = duplicate(struct2)

Comment: Structs are always passed by reference.  Duplicate() simply does a deep copy so that you have a new reference.